# why a specific model is not appropriate, given a data with 6 variables (they are chr variables)

Tags: r, statistics, linear-regression

i want to show why a specific model is not appropriate, given a data with 6 variables (they are chr variables)
the model is y= a*b*c*(x1+x2)
a and b from the data are non numeric, so is it enough to say that because they are not numeric we cant use this model?
and if i want to change a chr variables into numeric how can i do this without making it become NA?

Comment: Could you please share some code you already tried and data using `dput(df)`?

Comment: this is my codes until now.str(data3)
data3_num= as.data.frame(apply(data3, 2, as.numeric))
sapply(data3_num, class)
str(data3_num)
mydata= select(data3_num,c(3,4,5,6))
CM=cor(mydata)
CM
dput(data3)

Answer (score 0):

You can still potentially model non-numeric type data by converting it to factor by: `df$a <- as.factor(df$a); df$b <- as.factor(df$b)`.

However, it might not make sense sometimes. For example, `df$a` is an unique id for each observation and you don't want to put it as a predictor.